# Degree $d$ non-isomorphic graph count

Tags: graph-theory

How many non-isomorphic regular graphs are there are $n$-vertices with degree $d$?

Comment: I think this link will be useful:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77730/how-many-p-regular-graphs-with-n-vertices-are-there. Actually not so obvious as it seemed to be from the first glance.

Answer (score 1):

To give an idea of the difficulty  of this problem here is the case of
$d=2,$ which means we have a  multiset of cycles. As there is just one
cycle on  $n$ nodes and  the smallest cycle  is a triangle  these have
generating function $$C(z) = \frac{z^3}{1-z}.$$  We get for the set of
non-isomorphic  $2$-regular  graphs  the  generating  function  (Polya
Enumeration Theorem)

$$R_2(z) = 
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{1}{l} \frac{z^{3l}}{1-z^l}\right).$$

Differentiate to get

$$R'_2(z) = R_2(z)
\left(3\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{z^{3l-1}}{1-z^l}
+ \sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{z^{3l}}{(1-z^l)^2} z^{l-1}
\right)$$

or
$$z R'_2(z) = R_2(z)
\left(3\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{z^{3l}}{1-z^l}
+ \sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{z^{4l}}{(1-z^l)^2}
\right)
\\ = R_2(z)
\left(3\sum_{l\ge 1} \sum_{k\ge 0} z^{(k+3)l}
+ \sum_{l\ge 1} \sum_{k\ge 0} (k+1) z^{(k+4)l}
\right).$$

Introducing $r_{n,2}  = [z^n]  R_2(z)$ and extracting  coefficients we
get

$$n r_{n,2} = \sum_{p=0}^n r_{n-p, 2}
\left(3 \sum_{k+3|p\wedge k\ge 0} 1 
+ \sum_{k+4|p\wedge k\ge 0} (k+1)\right).$$

Now the multiplier on $R_2(z)$ on  the RHS does not include a constant
term in fact it starts at $[z^3]$ so this is

$$r_{n,2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p=3}^{n} r_{n-p, 2}
\left(3 \sum_{k+3|p\wedge k\ge 0} 1 
+ \sum_{k+4|p\wedge k\ge 0} (k+1)\right).$$

for $n\ge  3$ with base cases $r_{0,2}  = 1$ and $r_{1,2}  = r_{2,2} =
0.$ (There are some zero terms in the sum that could be omitted.)

This recurrence produces the sequence

$$1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 17, 21, 25, 
\\ 33, 39, 49, 60, 73, 88,\ldots$$

which  is  [OEIS  A008483](https://oeis.org/A008483), partitions  into
parts $\ge 3$, which perfectly matches the problem definition.

Comment: are you saying $0=0+0+0$, $3=1+1+1$ and so on?

Comment: 'partitions into parts ≥3'?

Comment: I think you might need to show and document your research on this question to get it to be re-opened.

Comment: @markriedel I will do that but what do you mean by partitions into parts $\geq3$. Is this about number of ways to write an integer (say $400$) into sum of at least $3$ parts (like $400=250+140+10$)?

Comment: Any number of parts, parts at least three in value.

Comment: oh so $400=3+104+140+153$ works but not $400=2+2+396$ right?